# how to draw a tree structure in php from mysql data?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

i have the below mysql records, so need to draw a tree structure in php by using the below mysql data, here `NULL` value represent the main parent node,

```
+----------------+----------------+
| child          | parent         |
+----------------+----------------+
| 216            |            103 |
| 217            |            216 |
| 88             |            216 |
| 102            |           NULL |
| 103            |            102 |
| 104            |            102 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

the output should be a below format

```
               102
              /   \ 
            103    104
            /
          216
         /  \
       217   218
```

please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? Can you show us some code please?

Comment: sorry i've no idea to achive this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function for making an array for child-parent:

```
function parseTree($tree, $root = null) {
    $return = array();
    # Traverse the tree and search for direct children of the root
    foreach($tree as $child => $parent) {
        # A direct child is found
        if($parent == $root) {
            # Remove item from tree (we don't need to traverse this again)
            unset($tree[$child]);
            # Append the child into result array and parse its children
            $return[] = array(
                'name' => $child,
                'children' => parseTree($tree, $child)
            );
        }
    }
    return empty($return) ? null : $return;    
}
```

For output:

```
function printtree($tree) {
    if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $node) {
            echo '<li>'.$node['name'];
            printTree($node['children']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Full PHP script:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'216'=>103,
'217'=>216,
'88'=>216,
'102'=>NULL,
'103'=>102,
'104'=>102
);
function parseTree($tree, $root = null) {
    $return = array();
    # Traverse the tree and search for direct children of the root
    foreach($tree as $child => $parent) {
        # A direct child is found
        if($parent == $root) {
            # Remove item from tree (we don't need to traverse this again)
            unset($tree[$child]);
            # Append the child into result array and parse its children
            $return[] = array(
                'name' => $child,
                'children' => parseTree($tree, $child)
            );
        }
    }
    return empty($return) ? null : $return;    
}

function printtree($tree) {
    if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $b) {
            echo '<li>'.$b['name'];
            printtree($b['children']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

printtree(parseTree($arr));
?>
```

Output:

- 102

  - 103

    - 216

      - 217
      - 88
  - 104

small CSS one could use :-

```
li 
    { 
        position: relative; 
        margin-left: -15px;
        list-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: what u mean in $tree?

Comment: tree, in function parseTree is the array you want to convert into parent-child. :)

Comment: yeah it's fine, please say any possibilities to add css too :)

Comment: `li
    {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -15px;
        list-style: none;
        border-left:2px solid red;
         border-bottom:2px solid red;
    }`                                                                              please correct this

Comment: hi, it's not working with below array format                                                `Array ( [192.168.10.216] => 192.168.40.103 [192.168.10.217] => 192.168.10.216 [192.168.10.88] => 192.168.10.216 [192.168.40.102] => NULL [192.168.40.103] => 192.168.40.102 [192.168.40.104] => 192.168.40.102 ) '